# H2o Rd warning: "Missing File Link"

Tags: r, h2o, automl

When downloading H2o.ai from R on my linux, I receive several warnings that a file is missing, For example:     `Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.abs.Rd:32: missing file link 'abs'`

I'm using the standard install code for H2o: `install.packages("h2o", type="source", repos="http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-xu/1/R")`

Here is the output with the warnings: 
    `    h2o.abs                                 html
    Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.abs.Rd:32: missing file link ‘abs’
        h2o.acos                                html
    Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.acos.Rd:24: missing file link ‘acos’

```
    h2o.ascharacter                         html  
Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.ascharacter.Rd:16: missing file link ‘as.character’
    h2o.asfactor                            html  
Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.asfactor.Rd:16: missing file link ‘as.factor’
    h2o.asnumeric                           html  
Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.asnumeric.Rd:16: missing file link ‘as.numeric’

    h2o.ceiling                             html  
Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.ceiling.Rd:18: missing file link ‘ceiling’

Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.cos.Rd:16: missing file link ‘cos’
    h2o.cosh                                html  
Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.cosh.Rd:16: missing file link ‘cosh’
    h2o.coxph                               html  
    h2o.createFrame                         html  
    h2o.cross_validation_fold_assignment    html  
    h2o.cross_validation_holdout_predictions
                                            html  
    h2o.cross_validation_models             html  
    h2o.cross_validation_predictions        html  
    h2o.cummax                              html  
Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.cummax.Rd:18: missing file link ‘cummax’
    h2o.cummin                              html  
Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.cummin.Rd:18: missing file link ‘cummin’
    h2o.cumprod                             html  
Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.cumprod.Rd:18: missing file link ‘cumprod’
    h2o.exp                                 html  
Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.exp.Rd:16: missing file link ‘exp’

    h2o.floor                               html  
Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.floor.Rd:18: missing file link ‘floor’

    h2o.ischaracter                         html  
Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.ischaracter.Rd:16: missing file link ‘is.character’
    h2o.isfactor                            html  
Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.isfactor.Rd:16: missing file link ‘is.factor’
    h2o.isnumeric                           html  
Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.isnumeric.Rd:16: missing file link ‘is.numeric’

Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.log.Rd:16: missing file link ‘log’
    h2o.log10                               html  
Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.log10.Rd:16: missing file link ‘log10’
    h2o.log1p                               html  
Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.log1p.Rd:16: missing file link ‘log1p’
    h2o.log2                                html  
Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.log2.Rd:16: missing file link ‘log2’

Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.max.Rd:18: missing file link ‘max’
    h2o.mean                                html  
Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.mean.Rd:46: missing file link ‘rowMeans’
Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.mean.Rd:46: missing file link ‘colMeans’

Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.min.Rd:18: missing file link ‘min’

Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.ncol.Rd:16: missing file link ‘ncol’

Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.rbind.Rd:32: missing file link ‘rbind’

Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.round.Rd:21: missing file link ‘round’

Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.signif.Rd:21: missing file link ‘signif’
    h2o.sin                                 html  
Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.sin.Rd:16: missing file link ‘sin’

Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.sqrt.Rd:16: missing file link ‘sqrt’

Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.tan.Rd:16: missing file link ‘tan’
    h2o.tanh                                html  
Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.tanh.Rd:16: missing file link ‘tanh’

Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.trunc.Rd:17: missing file link ‘trunc’

Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.var.Rd:36: missing file link ‘var’

Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.which_max.Rd:29: missing file link ‘which.max’

 building package indices
 testing if installed package can be loaded
 DONE (h2o)
```

I believe this issue is causing a downstream error when using automl, `Error: DistributedException from localhost/127.0.0.1:54321: 'Categorical value out of bounds`

Comment: can you provide some more information about your environment and all the steps you took before trying to install h2o-3. So far when downloading from source or cran on linux the download hasn't thrown the errors you've seen.

Answer (score 0):

Those are errors in the package, but not very serious ones.  For example, the first one you list

```
Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpdpaSKI/R.INSTALL1d3a6ccc7d9b/h2o/man/h2o.ascharacter.Rd:16: missing file link ‘as.character’
```

comes because that help file contains the link `\link[base]{as.character}` which does not exist.  It should be `\link[base]{character}` or `\link[base:character]{as.character}`, since links to other packages are to the help page name, not to the topic alias.  If you ask for help using `?h2o.ascharacter`, you might find the link in the help page to `as.character` doesn't work.  (Usually such links do work, because the R dynamic help system figures out what the author meant, but some installations use a static help system with pre-built `.html` files where the links won't work.)

The rules for cross-package links in the help system are pretty bizarre, and it looks like the `h2o` authors didn't learn them (or didn't care about static help).

I don't know if your guess about the downstream error is right or not.

Answer (score 0):

Can you say more about the system that you're using and the version of R?  I am not able to reproduce this on Ubuntu 16.04.5 using R 3.4.4.  I tried installing exactly how you did and also just by installing the latest from CRAN (both are version 3.22.0.1).

```
> install.packages("h2o")
Installing package into '/home/ledell/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/h2o_3.22.1.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 432390 bytes (422 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 422 KB

* installing *source* package 'h2o' ...
** package 'h2o' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** demo
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Performing one-time download of h2o.jar from
     http://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-release/h2o/rel-xu/1/Rjar/h2o.jar
(This could take a few minutes, please be patient...)
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (h2o)

The downloaded source packages are in
    '/tmp/RtmpGwtVRB/downloaded_packages'


> install.packages("h2o", type="source", repos="http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-xu/1/R")
Installing package into '/home/ledell/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-xu/1/R/src/contrib/h2o_3.22.1.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-tar' length 120971891 bytes (115.4 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 115.4 MB

* installing *source* package 'h2o' ...
** R
** demo
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (h2o)

The downloaded source packages are in
    '/tmp/RtmpGwtVRB/downloaded_packages'
```

The downstream error is not related.  If you can post the code you are running as a separate question with reproducible code, we can try to sort that out.